# Teradata min/max of each column

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a big table (>50 columns), and want to get max and min of each column like this:

```
column_1 min max
column_n min max
```

Is there any query to do so?

Comment: It's much more effcient when you `select min(column_1), max(column_1), min(column_2), etc.` instead of running 50 queries.

Comment: Single pass of the table as suggested by @dnoeth is the more efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'column_01', min(column_1), max(column_1) from tablename
union all
select 'column_02', min(column_2), max(column_2) from tablename
...
union all
select 'column_50', min(column_50), max(column_50) from tablename
```